# Is Tuvok the only black Vulcan?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, vulcan

I spotted the following interview quoting from TV Zone magazine with Tim Russ talking about what it means to be "*the* black Vulcan".

> Tim Russ knows the reality of his place in Star Trek: Voyager. Whether
> he likes it or not, his character, Starfleet Tactical-Security Officer
> Tuvok, is the next big Vulcan, but Russ, ever the candid individual,
> knows that simply being a Vulcan is not the big hook.
>
> **“I’m being
> pushed as the black Vulcan,”** chuckles Russ. **“Look at me. I am black.
> It’s something I can’t get around so I might as well use it to my
> advantage. I don’t feel uncomfortable being pushed that way. It’s not
> like the question isn’t going to be brought up so I might as well
> accept it.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[I am not Spock! - TVZone Interview - Tim Russ](http://www.timrusstribute.com/interviews/TV%20Zone73.htm)</sup></sub>

Inspired by [this (alas, now deleted) question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144558/were-there-black-vulcans), were there *other* black Vulcans found elsewhere in the Star Trek canon, especially any that pre-date Tuvok/Voyager?

Comment: Also, there's another [Black Vulcan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Vulcan)

Comment: @starpilotsix - Damn him. He keeps coming up in every bloody search I do.

Comment: Since the question is as you noted deleted, what was its premise? I'm curious.

Comment: @1252748 - Very similar. Just worded differently; https://i.stack.imgur.com/nntdN.png. Since Hack-R decided to delete it (after getting a few downvotes), I figured I'd post it up and self-answer since I already had most of an answer mapped out

Comment: Until this moment, even though I've watched all of Voyager through twice, I didn't notice Tuvok was black.

Comment: @Jocie - I can only imagine your shock when you realise that Janeway is a woman.

Comment: @Valorum - WHAT?! I don't believe you!!!

Comment: LOGICALLY, his parents must have been black as well. :P

Comment: @Steve-O - Curse you and your pointy ears.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, absolutely there have been other black-skinned Vulcans elsewhere in the main Star Trek canon, with several pre-dating Tim Russ's casting in Voyager. It should be noted that Tuvok is referred to in his [StarTrek.com biography](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/vulcans) as being a ...

> **full Vulcan**

... which strongly implies that having dark skin is a natural racial trait among Vulcans and in no way connected to interbreeding with other dark-skinned aliens.

---

*In order of appearance:*

**Vulcan Midwife**
[image]
[Star Trek III: The Search for Spock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088170/) (1984)

**Vulcan Priestess** (played by [Beverly Hart](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Beverly_Hart))
[image]
[Star Trek V: The Final Frontier](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098382/) (1989)

**Unnamed Vulcan in Bar**
[image]
[TNG: Preemptive Strike](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Preemptive_Strike_(episode)) (1994)

---

**T'Pel (Tuvok's wife)** (played by [Marva Hicks](http://Marva%20Hicks))
[image]
[VOY: Persistence of Vision](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Persistence_of_Vision_(episode)) (1995)

**T'Kumbra Crew Member / Vulcan Baseball Player** (played by [Brett Bartlett](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_T%27Kumbra_personnel))
[image]
[DS9: Take Me Out to the Holosuite](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Take_Me_Out_to_the_Holosuite_(episode)) (1998)

**Sek (Tuvok's son)**  (played by [Ronald Robinson](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_Robinson))
[image]
[VOY: Repression](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Repression_(episode)) (2000)

**Vulcan Monk**  (played by [Larry Tolliver](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Larry_Tolliver))
[image]
[ENT: The Andorian Incident](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Andorian_Incident_(episode)) (2001)

**Vulcan Student** (played by [Sean Michael Tilghman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sean_Michael_Tilghman))
[image]
[Star Trek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_(film)) (2009)

**Vulcan Council Member**  (played by [Brian Waller](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Brian_Waller))
[image]
[Star Trek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_(film)) (2009)

Comment: "*Just as TNG’s Lt. Worf broadened the background of the Klingon empire to include a variety of skin tones, Lt. Tuvok would do the same for the Vulcans. “We came up with the wrinkle of making him a black Vulcan,” said Jeri Taylor. “We had just used a black Romulan on TNG [in ‘The Pegasus’] that we thought was a nice touch. Subsequently I have learned we were not the first. In the third feature there was a black Vulcan priestess, **so it was clearly established there were different colors of people on Vulcan**.”*" - http://www.timrusstribute.com/interviews/Cinefantastique1st.htm

Comment: I think? There was a black vulcan in one of the TNG movies. The Zefram Cochrane versus the Borg one.

Comment: @FinnO'leary - IMDB lists the three Vulcans in '[First Contact](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117731/fullcredits/)' as Cully Fredricksen (Caucasian), Noelle Hannibal (Caucasian) and Louis Ortiz (Hispanic).