# Where in Ireland is Miles O'Brien from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

Obviously O'Brien is Irish, but is it ever clear which city/county/region in Ireland he comes from?

Comment: He's Irish? Why didn't anyone tell me?

Comment: Then again, [other people have also failed to notice minor character traits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144568/is-tuvok-the-only-black-vulcan#comment369638_144568)

Comment: TNG & DS9 are centuries after owning automobiles became very commoon n Earth, and Ireland is a relatively small region.  Most modern Americans move every few years. So why do you think that O'Brien should be form a place in Ireland instead of from many different places in and out of Ireland and on and off Earth he has lived in.

Comment: While it seems that O'Brien is *ethnically* Irish, it's not obvious that he was born there. Hikaru Sulu was played as obviously ethnically Japanese in TOS but he was actually [born in California](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hikaru_Sulu), so some might describe him as Japanese-American or Asian-American rather than Japanese per se. Of course, there's a very big Japanese-American community in California (and also Hawaii) today, so it makes sense that there might still be a viable ethnic community there in the 23rd century to pass along the culture.

Answer (score 21):

### O'Brien's place of birth is [Killarney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killarney), Ireland, Earth.

This is confirmed in a couple of places.

Per [*The Star Trek Book: Strange New Worlds Boldly Explained*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Trek_Book):

> **NAME:** Miles Edward O’Brien
>
> **SPECIES:** Human
>
> **BORN: 2328,** **Killarney, Ireland, Earth**
>
> **FATHER:** Michael O’Brien
>
> **STARFLEET DIVISION:** Operations

and [Startrek.com](https://intl.startrek.com/database_article/obrien-miles):

> **PERSONNEL FILE:** **O'Brien, Miles Edward**
>
> **Rank:** Chief petty officer, senior chief specialist
> **Full Name:** Miles Edward O'Brien
> **Year of birth:** September, 2328
> **Place of birth:** **Killarney, Ireland, Earth**
> **Parents:** Mr. and Mrs. Michael O'Brien (mother died 2368; father remarried 2369)
>
> <sub><sup>[Personnel File: Miles O'Brien](https://intl.startrek.com/database_article/obrien-miles)</sup></sub>

Interestingly, this location was part of the original script for *DS9: Homefront*, but changed to Dublin for unknown reasons, presumably because most Americans would be more familiar with Dublin or simply to reflect Colm Meaney's accent:

> **O'BRIEN:** *Look, Odo... Do me a favor? If you get a chance, drop by and visit my folks in Killarney.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Homefront - Original Screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/483.txt)</sup></sub>

---

As noted in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/253942/20774), Miles has ties to Dublin and that's where his parents currently live. Various of the EU novels mention that he grew up there. For example:

> Keiko knew there was little chance of Molly falling over, as her
> father was holding the back of the antique bicycle that she was
> struggling to learn to ride. She even kidded him that everyone must
> have ridden bicycles when he was a little boy growing up on Earth, but
> he assured her that he wasn’t that old. **“I learned a lot younger than
> you when I was a little boy in Dublin,”** he said. “My brothers taught
> me. There’s no better way to learn balance.”
>
> <sub><sup>[DS0: Lesser Evil](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lesser_Evil)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 5):

As far I can tell, no canon episode or film has ever specified which part of Ireland O'Brien was born in, or grew up in.

His personnel file on [StarTrek.com](https://www.startrek.com/database_article/obrien-miles) states that he was born in **Killarney, Ireland**.

> [image]

However, his personnel file in the *[Star Trek: Starship Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Starship_Creator)* game states that he was born in **Dublin, Ireland**.

> [image]

---

It has been established in canon that his *parents* live in Dublin (DS9: "[Homefront](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Homefront_(episode))").

> ODO: Well, I take it the Battle of Britain has been won yet again.
>
> BASHIR: There's a Spitfire with your name on it waiting in the hangar. When you get back from Earth, you can take Clive's place in the squadron.
>
> ODO: Somehow I doubt it.
>
> O'BRIEN: **Look, Odo, do me a favour. If you get a chance, stop by and visit my folks in Dublin. Just make sure they're okay, you know?**
>
> ODO: I'll try to find the time.
>
> O'BRIEN: Good. I'll let them know you might drop by.
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* - S04E11 - "Homefront"</sub>

And the *[Star Trek Encyclopedia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia)* states that his *family* resides in Dublin, possibly implying that he has other relatives there.

> **O'Brien's family resided in Dublin, Ireland, on Earth** ("Homefront" [DS9]). His ancestors included noted 20th-century union leader, Sean Aloysius O'Brien and 11th-century Irish King Brian Boru. ("Bar Association" [DS9]).
>
> <sub>*Star Trek Encyclopedia*</sub>

Comment: An interesting find, but not one that confirms his birthplace, only where his parents are living.

Comment: The question didn't strictly ask where he was _born_, it asked where he's _from_. And if you asked him, he might say he's from Dublin, if that's where he grew up, and where he last lived when he resided on Earth. He does have a Dublin accent, as others have noted.

Comment: Your nitpick is noted, hence why you got a comment and not a downvote. It still doesn't confirm that he's ever lived there though. My parents live about three hundred miles from where I'm 'from'

Comment: It doesn't confirm he ever lived in Dublin, but it's the only clue as to which specific part of Ireland he might have lived in that is given within an actual episode or film.

Comment: Well, that and his strong and unmistakeable Dublin accent.

Answer (score 2):

### Killarney in County Kerry

I found numerous sources claiming this, including the [Spanish Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/es/wiki/Miles_O%27Brien) wiki and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_O%27Brien_(Star_Trek)), which cites it to Appendix B of the book *Star Trek Chronology: The History of the Future* (1996).

There's even a [petition](https://www.ipetitions.com/petition/honour-killarney-county-kerry-as-the-future) to honour him by having a plaque put up in the real town of [Killarney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killarney). It was not successful; I guess there isn't a huge density of Star Trek fans in County Kerry.

It should also be noted that he speaks with a **Dublin** accent in the show, following the actor [Colm Meaney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colm_Meaney) who is from Dublin. Some [fans fear](https://twitter.com/mrstackpoole/status/1217011412381380613) that this means Dublin has expanded to cover almost the whole island of Ireland by the 24th century, but perhaps a more likely explanation is that Miles O'Brien was born in Killarney and grew up in Dublin.

Comment: The *Spanish* memory alpha?

Comment: 'Twas news to me too that such exists.

Comment: That Wikipedia citation (ST: Chronology) appears to be confirming the date of his birth, not his birthplace.